# MySQL backup breakes a table every time

Tags: mysql

I've a MySQL Server 5.1.58-1ubuntu1 installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Every night we do a backup of all the databases with this script:

```
rm -rf /var/backup/mysql/ *
for i in $(echo 'SHOW DATABASES;' | mysql -u root -p'password' |grep -v '^Database$'); do
mysqldump \
-u root -p'password' \
-Q -c -C --add-drop-table --add-locks --quick --lock-tables \
$i > /var/backup/mysql/$i.sql;
tar -cpzf /var/backup/mysql/$i.sql.tar.gz /var/backup/mysql/$i.sql;
rm -rf /var/backup/mysql/$i.sql
done;
```

Every time the backup is executed a particular MySQL table is broken (the MYD and MYI files are deleted, while the FRM remains).

We have many databases and tables, only this one is broken.

Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean "broken" ? place some log

Comment: Broken = The MYD (data) and MYI (indexes) files for this table disappear (only FRM file remains). I can create the table again (and I check that the MYD, MYI and FRM files exists), and every night-backup the MYD and MYI files are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Finally I tried to rename the table and now it stops getting corrupted every day! It seems that MySQL have some internal registry indicating a problem with the previous table name.